# Moving an Object according to mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, canvas

How do I get the following script to work?  I wanted to be able to move the ship to the mouse coordinates. The space itself should move and the ship should stay in the centerview. 
Would be great if you can modify the script as everybody writes his functions different.

Finally if the button is clicked I want the ship to move to that destination
I tried it when it worked and the ship never moved and I don't know if it has to do with the `prototype.update` function or not.

Is `prototype.update` or `.render` the same as if I would write `this.update` or `this.render`?

```js
<script>
function domanDown(evt)
{
switch (evt)
        {
                case 38:  /* Up arrow was pressed or button pressed*/
                offsetY+=100 ;
                break;
                case 40:  /* Down arrow was pressed or button pressed*/
                offsetY-=100;
                break;
                case 37:  /* Left arrow was pressedor button pressed*/
                offsetX+=100;
                break;
                case 39:  /* Right arrow was pressed or button pressed*/
                offsetX-=100;
                break;
        }
}
window.requestAnimationFrame = function() {
 return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
  function(f) {
   window.setTimeout(f,1e3/60);
  }
}();
     var Obj = function (x,y,sp,size){
      this.size = size;
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
         this.color = sp;
      this.selected = 0;
     }
      var Planet_Class = function (x,y,sp){
      this.type = 'Planet_Class';
      this.depot = 11;
      this.xtype = new Obj(x,y,sp,10);
        w.objects.push(this);     
       Planet_Class.prototype.update =function () {  
      }
      Planet_Class.prototype.render =function () {  
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = this.xtype.color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.xtype.x, this.xtype.y,this.xtype.size,this.xtype.size);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();
      }
     }
     var Usership = function(x,y,sp){
     this.depot = 10;
     this.type = 'Usership';
     this.xtype = new Obj(x,y,sp,10);
     w.objects.push(this);
     Usership.prototype.update =function (x,y) {  
     this.xtype.x = x || 20;
     this.xtype.y = y || 20;
     }
     Usership.prototype.render =function () {  
     ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.fillStyle = this.xtype.color;
     ctx.fillRect(this.xtype.x, this.xtype.y,this.xtype.size,this.xtype.size);
     ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();
     }
     }
     var World = function(){     
      this.objects = new Array();
      this.count = function(type,sp){
       var cnt = 0;    
       for(var k = 0;k<this.objects.length;k++)
       cnt++;
      return cnt;
      }
     }
     renderWorld = function(){
      requestAnimationFrame(renderWorld);
      var spliceArray = Array();
      ctx.beginPath();
      objcnt = w.objects.length;
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
         ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.fill();   
      i = 0;
      while(i < objcnt){         
         w.objects[i].update();        
      w.objects[i].render();    
      if(w.objects[i].depot < 1)
      spliceArray.push(i);           
      i++;   
      }
      for(var k = 0;k<spliceArray.length;k++)  
      {
      w.objects.splice(spliceArray[k],1);  }
      
     }
     function r1(max,min){
      return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + 1);
     }
      canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
      width = 1024,
      height = 768;
      offsetX = (canvas.width/2)-300;   /Startpoint x for the Ship
      offsetY = (canvas.height/2)-300;   /Startpoint y for the Ship
      generateshipx = -offsetX + (canvas.width/2);
      generateshipy = -offsetY + (canvas.height/2);
      mX = generateshipx;     
      mY = generateshipy;   
      w = new World();
      new Usership(generateshipx,generateshipy,'green');
         for(i=1;i<4;i++){
       new Planet_Class(r1(600,2),r1(600,2),'red');
      }
      canvas.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      mX = e.pageX- canvas.offsetLeft -offsetX) ;
      mY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop -offsetY) ;
      });
      renderWorld();

  </script>
```

```html
 
<html>
<head>
 </head>
 <body  style="background-color:black;">
  
 <canvas style="z-index:1" width="1024" height="768" id="canvas"></canvas>
<input type="button" style="z-index:2; position:absolute; top:300; left:10" value="uo" onCLick="domanDown(38)()">
<input type="button" style="z-index:2; position:absolute; top:340; left:10" value="down" onCLick="domanDown(40)">
<input type="button" style="z-index:2; position:absolute; top:380; left:10" value="left" onCLick="domanDown(37)">
<input type="button" style="z-index:2; position:absolute; top:420; left:10" value="right" onCLick="domanDown(39)">
<input type="button" style="z-index:2; position:absolute; top:460; left:10" value="move" onCLick="moveObj()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qvL1ufka/ there are error in your code. I have corrected some of them.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
   body {
    background-color: black;
   }
   
   canvas {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    cursor: crosshair;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 10px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script type="application/javascript">
   
   var canvasWidth = 180;
   var canvasHeight = 160;
   var canvas = null;
   var ctx = null;
   var bounds = null;
   var isRotating = false;
   var isMoving = false;
   
   var pan = {
    x: 0.0,
    y: 0.0
   };
   
   var target = {
    x: 0.0,
    y: 0.0,
    dist: 0.0
   };
   
   var ship = {
    x: (canvasWidth * 0.5)|0,
    y: (canvasHeight * 0.5)|0,
    width: 10.0,
    height: 10.0,
    rotation: 0.0,
    deltaRotation: 0.0
   };
   
   var stars = [];
    stars.length = 100;
   
   window.onload = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = canvasWidth;
    canvas.height = canvasHeight;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; ++i) {
     stars[i] = {
      x: (Math.random() * 4 * canvasWidth - 2 * canvasWidth)|0,
      y: (Math.random() * 4 * canvasHeight - 2 * canvasHeight)|0
     };
    }
    
    loop();
   }
   
   window.onmousedown = function(e) {
    isRotating = true;
    isMoving = false;
    target.x = pan.x + e.clientX - bounds.left;
    target.y = pan.y + e.clientY - bounds.top;
   }
   
   function loop() {
    // Tick
    // Rotate to face target
    if (isRotating) {
     // Vector creation
     var tX = ship.x - target.x;
     var tY = ship.y - target.y;
     var tL = Math.sqrt(tX**2 + tY**2);
     var fX = Math.sin(ship.rotation);
     var fY = -Math.cos(ship.rotation);
     var sX = Math.sin(ship.rotation + Math.PI * 0.5);
     var sY = -Math.cos(ship.rotation + Math.PI * 0.5); 
     
     // Normalization
     tX = tX / tL;
     tY = tY / tL;
     
     // Left or right?
     var a = 1.0 - Math.abs(tX * fX + tY * fY);
     ship.rotation +=  0.075 * (sX * tX + sY * tY < 0.0 ? 1.0 : -1.0);
     
     if (a < 0.01) {
      target.dist = tL;
      isRotating = false;
      isMoving = true;
     }
    }
    
    // Accelerate to target
    if (isMoving) {
     ship.x += Math.sin(ship.rotation) * 1.0;
     ship.y -= Math.cos(ship.rotation) * 1.0;
     
     if (--target.dist < 0.0) {
      isMoving = false;
     }
    }
   
    // Render
    // Update pan coordinates
    pan.x = ship.x - canvasWidth * 0.5;
    pan.y = ship.y - canvasHeight * 0.5;
   
    // Draw background
    ctx.fillStyle = "#222222";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; ++i) {
     ctx.fillRect(
      stars[i].x - pan.x,
      stars[i].y - pan.y,
      2,
      2
     );
    }
    
    // Draw ship
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillStyle = "darkred";
    ctx.translate(canvasWidth * 0.5,canvasHeight * 0.5);
    ctx.rotate(ship.rotation);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(-ship.width * 0.5,ship.height * 0.5);
    ctx.lineTo(ship.width * 0.5,ship.height * 0.5);
    ctx.lineTo(0.0,-ship.height * 0.5);
    ctx.lineTo(-ship.width * 0.5,ship.height * 0.5);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.rotate(-ship.rotation);
    ctx.translate(-canvasWidth * 0.5,-canvasHeight * 0.5);
    
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
   }
   
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```